# How to change response.message in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, response

Hello I am having given code

```
def create_profile(payment)
      return unless payment.source.gateway_customer_profile_id.nil?
      options = {
        email: payment.order.email,
        login: preferred_secret_key,
      }.merge! address_for(payment)

      source = update_source!(payment.source)
      if source.number.blank? && source.gateway_payment_profile_id.present?
        creditcard = source.gateway_payment_profile_id
      else
        creditcard = source
      end

      response = provider.store(creditcard, options)
      if response.success?
        cc_type=payment.source.cc_type
        response_cc_type = response.params['sources']['data'].first['brand']
        cc_type = CARD_TYPE_MAPPING[response_cc_type] if CARD_TYPE_MAPPING.include?(response_cc_type)

        payment.source.update_attributes!({
          cc_type: cc_type, # side-effect of update_source!
          gateway_customer_profile_id: response.params['id'],
          gateway_payment_profile_id: response.params['default_source'] || response.params['default_card']
        })

      else
        payment.send(:gateway_error, response.message)
      end
    end
```

I need to change message in response.message for that i had tried using `response = [ { message: "fraud card"} ].to_json` but it gives error `

```
undefined method `message' for "[{"message":"fraud card"}]":String
```

I had also tried `response.message = 'fraud error'`, still it gives error. Response I receive is :

```
params:
  error:
    message: Your card was declined.
    type: card_error
    code: card_declined
    decline_code: fraudulent
    charge: ch_1AgncyJEfCzWOpKDdoxn1x1R
message: Your card was declined.
success: false
test: false
authorization: ch_1AgncyJEfCzWOpKDdoxn1x1R
fraud_review: 
error_code: card_declined
emv_authorization: 
avs_result:
  code: 
  message: 
  street_match: 
  postal_match: 
cvv_result:
  code: 
  message:
```

Now my requirement is to check if decline_code is fraudulent than my message should be `fraud error`. please let me know how to change this.

Comment: doest response.message return a String? Does response object have a setter for message (i guess not)?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, you're using Spree Gateway. By passing a string instead of the proper response object, your solution circumvents [Spree's default implementation](https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/master/core/app/models/spree/payment/processing.rb#L157-L168) which logs error details for the response.

What I'd do instead is adapt the `gateway_error` method to your needs by following [Spree's suggested approach for logic customization](http://guides.spreecommerce.org/developer/logic.html):

```
# app/models/spree/payment_decorator.rb
Spree::Payment.class_eval do
  private

  def gateway_error(error)
    if error.is_a? ActiveMerchant::Billing::Response
      # replace this with your actual implementation, e.g. based on response.params['error']['code']
      text = 'fraud message'
    elsif error.is_a? ActiveMerchant::ConnectionError
      text = Spree.t(:unable_to_connect_to_gateway)
    else
      text = error.to_s
    end
    logger.error(Spree.t(:gateway_error))
    logger.error("  #{error.to_yaml}")
    raise Core::GatewayError.new(text)
  end
end
```

It's not the cleanest implementation since it does copy & paste for existing code. But that's just how Spree is (I've implemented and contributed to multiple Spree shops and it's always a bit painful when customizing logic, especially private logic).

Hope that helps.

Comment: I've updated my suggestion based on your comment and on my experience with Spree.